# Stellar.js remove white space top bottom

Tags: scroll, parallax, stellar.js

I use Stellar.js for parallax effect in a website a develop and I have unwanted white space at the bottom (and at top on my real website) when I scroll down. How can I remove this white space?

My stellar code initialisation:

```
$('body').stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalScrolling: true,
        verticalOffset: 0,
        horizontalOffset: 0,
        responsive: true,
        scrollProperty: 'scroll',
        parallaxElements: false,
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qf8uwgnb/